# How to kill this thread?

Tags: c#, .net

The four common methods to kill threads I've read are:

1. Use Thread.Interrupt to poke it if it is blocked.
2. Poll a flag variable.
3. Use the WaitHandle class to send a signal.
4. Thread.Abort()

Method four solves my problem but from what I understand, it is taboo to use so I just want to make sure that methods one to three do not work for me.

There is no sleeping or waiting so method one doesn't work. There is no while loop but there are several for loops so method two doesn't work. I only have one thread with no synchronization with other threads, so method three doesn't work. Therefore, I would be correct in using method four, right?

My application does a CPU-intensive algorithm on one thread. When the user exits the GUI, I want the computation to stop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Personally prefer method 2 `Poll a flag variable`, And I do not see why you can't use it as well.
So, You have several `for` loops, right? try the following:

```
for(int i=0; i< data1.length && !abortFlag; i++)
{
    //Do stuff
    for(int j=0; j< data2.length && !abortFlag; j++)
    {
        //Do more stuff
        for(int k=0; k< data3.length && !abortFlag; k++)
        {
            //Do even more stuff
        }
    }

}
```

Once you want to abort, simply set `abortFlag = true;`

One last thing. I think it is important to understand that there is no real difference between `for` and `while` loops. The difference is only semantics, you can accomplish same tasks with both.

**EDIT**
As per @Patrik's comment, when you share a variable for the purpose of managing threads (`abortFlag` in this case), it should be it should be marked as [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx):  `volatile int i;`

Comment: If there are no steps between each `for` loop statement, then you don't need to check the `abortFlag` value in every `for`, only the innermost one.

Comment: @Dai this is true, of course. The code sample is for the general case.

Comment: @Avi: I have several small for loops. This isn't really feasible as it would produce a ton of duplicate code.

Comment: I guess it's the only option but I wonder how much it will impact performance. I am iterating through the for loops a lot so it will spend a lot of time checking the flag, no?

Comment: Do not share a bool variable for the purpose of managing threads unless it's volatile.

Comment: @user3143211 Assuming you are doing some work in the loops, The affect will not be noticeable.

Comment: @Patrik Thank you for your note. I have modified the answer as per your comment.

Comment: did you mean `abortFlag`?